# pygame ang non-latin chars issue

Tags: python, character-encoding, pygame, non-ascii-characters

I've got such problem - when I pressing keyboard button in russian layout my application crushes with such message

**UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0444' in position 40: ordinal not in range(128)**

code:

```
 event = pygame.event.poll()
 if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    print(event)
```

(I've pressed latin 'a')
Pressing keys on English layout - works fine.

By the way - when I'm changing event.type == KEYDOWN to event.type == KEYUP - everything works, but in thi case I cannot access event.unicode param to get pressed key

Can some one advise me how to make it working with any keyboard layout KeyDown events?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line in the beginning of your file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: this is already added in each file and just tells to language interpreter in what encoding it should open file